# How to use custom post type plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on theme development in wordpress (and i am new to wordpress). i have started with Sage theme from Roots.

To archive what i need added image below[image]

I am using Content Post Type UI plugin to do this. I have no idea how to do this any help for tutorials would really appreciated.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: That is simple html/css, and data you can add as a simple post meta for the page it will be on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in supports 
see this in screenshots
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0595nlpbde

Have you check those options when you created the post type?

See this screenshots
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0705nlqdff

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom post type by user plugin content post type ui plugin and then add your title content and image in each post and fetch all posts on front end that's it.

Comment: but there is no option for adding title and image in the plugin, how do i add these